# How do I take a screenshot in Win10 in a way that places a URL into my clipboard instead of an image?

Tags: windows, clipboard, screenshot

I am taking a lot of screenshots (snippets of the screen, actually) and would like to have a one-click way to share (embeddable - with file extension) links of these uploaded images with others without having to manually upload them or copy a link.

I have been using Lightshot but it 1) requires you to manually copy a link and 2) the link it gives you is actually a webpage, and not an image.

Comment: To the close-votes. This question is worded in a way that avoids the product recommendation issue. OP was asking how to accomplish something, not specifying they need a recommendation for a product to accomplish it. It is also about computer hardware and software. The requested solution includes a web product, but the question is not primarily about that web product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Greenshot](http://getgreenshot.org/).

Greenshot will allow you to instantly upload your screenshot to Imgur and will put the direct image URL in your clipboard.

After you take a screenshot, you can either have it display a menu for you to select what you want to do with the screenshot (default behavior):

[image]

...or you can configure it to automatically upload to Imgur, eliminating an extra click:

[image]

Comment: How did you find this?!  I've been searching for hours.  Thank you.

Comment: @user666 You're welcome. I've been using it for a long time. Glad it helped.

Comment: Pretty much all screenshot assist applications office this feature. Greenshot is one such. I personally prefer/use ShareX, which also does this.